# Combining two tables and how to look for a record that contains two values from one table at least once

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose there is a table for loans made in the library - (loan_no, member_no, book_no)
and another table for a book (book_no, book_type, some other details)

I want to select the records where one book from two different book categories were borrowed.

For example, if loan_no includes one book each from book_type 'CRIME' and 'SCIENCE FICTION', I'd like to select it - and just that.
How would I go about it?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    loan
JOIN    book
ON      book.book_no = loan.book_no
WHERE   <loan_no contains book.book_category = 'SCIENCE FICTION' AND 'CRIME'>
```

Thank you.

CN

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  How can a "loan" have multiple books?  I would expect `loan_no` to be unique in a table called `loans`.  Can a book be in more than one  category?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify:
Loan_no is not unique and represents a single book borrowed under that loan_no. As such if multiple books were borrowed, there would be multiple entries under a single Loan_no.

In hindsight, using a nested function would have been easier. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `loan` table has multiple rows for a give `loan`, then you can use aggregation:

```
select l.loan_no
from loan l join
     book b
     using (book_no)
where b.book_category in ('SCIENCE FICTION', 'CRIME')
group by l.loan_no
having count(distinct b.book_category) = 2;
```